# Azure AD - Python SDK

Tags: python, azure, azure-python-sdk

It is possible to manage users/groups (AAD) and create automations via Python SDK?
My goal is to add email aliases to specific users with Python instead of PS.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you seen the Microsoft Graph Python SDK here: https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-python-core.

Comment: Yep. I succeeded to update the mail (SMTP) value with my Python code.
But -- I can't found the way to update my proxy addresses (aliases).
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http 
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

We have few classes in Python where we can manage the credentials and set the emails for them.

Usually emails will be as Username, have a look on parameters we have.

[Params](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iU2zY.png)

```
credential = DefaultAzureCredential()
blob_client = BlobClient(storage_url, container_name="blob-container-01",
    blob_name="sample-blob.txt", credential=credential,
    proxies={ "https": "https://username:password@10.10.1.10:1180" }
)
```

Also below link will help you out with all the functions that can sync with Azure Users and its groups, Setting mail servers, sending mails, adding user to groups etc..

[Documentation](https://gist.github.com/MaStr11/a3649c4f7e3d8fde286102cf2116a01a)

Below are the two functions which are helpful for configuring:

```
def addLocalUser(username, email):
    pwd=getGeneratedPassword()
    subprocess.check_call(['synouser', '--add', username.encode('utf8'), pwd.encode('utf8'), email.encode('utf8'), '0', email.encode('utf8'), '0'])
    addUserToGroup(username, Settings.SynoGroupName)
    logger.debug('Added user.')
    return pwd
        
    
def addLocalUserAndSendMail(email):
    username=email.replace(u'@',Settings.SynoAtSignReplacement)
    pwd=addLocalUser(username, email)
    sendMail(email, Settings.MailSubject, Settings.MailBody.format(username, pwd))
```